# Getting text inside of an element from the class name using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am trying to get the text inside the element using the class name from the link https://tracker.gg/valorant/profile/riot/SYNCO%23PYNCO/overview

Tried to get the "last match" text from the html class. This is the code :

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const url = 'https://tracker.gg/valorant/profile/riot/SYNCO%23PYNCO/overview';

async function run() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);

    const wepon = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const wepon = document.querySelector('.weapon .weapon__main-stat').innerText;
        return wepon;
    });

    console.log(wepon);

    // Wait for the page to load
    await page.waitForSelector('iframe');

    // Get the iframe element
    const iframe = await page.$('iframe');

    // Switch to the iframe's context
    const frame = await iframe.contentFrame();

    // Wait for the elements inside the iframe to load
    await frame.waitForSelector('.timeline-match');

    // Get the text of the first timeline-match element
    const elementText = await frame.$eval('.timeline-match', element => element.innerText);

    console.log(elementText);

    await browser.close();
}

run();
```

Comment: I don't see any inner text in that element. It seems to contain two `<span>` elements, maybe you want the inner text of those?

Comment: Can't I get both ? since it contains both?

Comment: Not the way you're doing it. Add `*` at the end of your selector to get a set of 2 spans for each `.weapon__main-stat` that you match, then map those to get `innerText`

Comment: You've told us what you're doing. Make it easier by telling us what's going wrong.

Comment: What's the expected output? I see "Last 20 Matches" but not "last match".

Comment: Hey! I am trying to output the match history data, for example the last one is 
5d ago
13 : 0
K/D 1.4
and so on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no iframes on the page I can see. You can get the timeline match data with normal selectors:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.6.3

const url = "<Your URL>";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36";
  await page.setUserAgent(ua);
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  await page.waitForSelector(".timeline-match");
  const matches = await page.$$eval(".timeline-match", els =>
    els.map(e => {
      const text = s => e.querySelector(s).textContent.trim();
      return {
        score: {
          winner: +text(".timeline-match__score--winner"),
          loser: +text(".timeline-match__score--winner"),
        },
        kd: text(".timeline-match__kd"),
        timestamp: text(".timeline-match__timestamp"),
      };
    })
  );
  console.log(matches);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

The page requests many resources, so I'd suggest blocking any visual styles and images you don't need, as well as any scripts or XHR requests not necessary to get the data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to get the text of the two span elements in the `.weapon__main-stat` element. Try updating "wepon" to this,

```
const wepon = await page.evaluate(() => {
  const weponElement = document.querySelector('.weapon__main-stat');
  const spans = weponElement.querySelectorAll('span');
  const spanTexts = Array.from(spans).map(span => span.innerText);
  return spanTexts.join(' - ');
});
```

Comment: `page.$eval('.weapon__main-stat', weaponElement => { ... })` is a macro for the common "query first thing in an `evaluate()` call" pattern. Better yet, use `page.$$eval(".weapon__main-stat span", els => els.map(e => e.textContent).join(" - "))` to do both queries in one.